# Short exact sequence of groups, is it possible to construct an associated fibration of spaces?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

Let$$0 \to R \to F \to G \to 0$$be a short exact sequence of groups. Is it possible to construct an associated fibration of spaces$$K(R, 1) \to K(F, 1) \to K(G, 1)?$$

Answer (score 3):

Yes. In fact a fiber sequence of Eilenberg-MacLane spaces is the same thing as a short exact sequence of groups.

Comment: Is it possible you could go a bit more into detail about this construction or supply a reference about this construction?

Comment: @Student: take a surjective group homomorphism $f : G \to H$. This induces a map $Bf : BG \to BH$ on classifying spaces / Eilenberg-MacLane spaces (how to see this at the point-set level depends on what your point-set construction of Eilenberg-MacLane spaces is). Now take the homotopy fiber (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_fiber) of $Bf$. A computation with the long exact sequence in homotopy shows that it is $B\text{ker}(f)$.

Comment: @Justin: that map is not surjective on $\pi_1$.

Comment: @Justin: oh, sorry, I misunderstood your example. Above $G$ and $H$ are supposed to be discrete groups.

Comment: I retract my example $B\mathbb Z /2 \to B S^1 \to B S^1$ is a fiber sequence induced by the squaring map on $S^1$, it's just not a fiber sequence of $K(G,1)$s.